# Ember.js - Get all bindings from an ember object

Tags: ember.js

Is the a better way of getting all the ember bindings from an object than this:

```
  Ember.keys(@).forEach (key) =>
    re = /\b[A-Za-z]*Binding\b/
    if key.match(re)
      prop = key.replace('Binding', "")
      controller.set(prop, @get(prop)) if @get(prop)
```

This works but seems problematic.

What I am doing is trying to get all the bindings defined in an .hbs file and set them on another object.